# Scala implicit conversion + parameter together with Play2 controller/view

Tags: scala, playframework, implicit-conversion, implicit

I have the following play2 code:

```
  implicit def contextToRequest(rc: RequestContext[_]) = rc.request
  implicit def contextToFlash(rc: RequestContext[_]) = rc.request.flash
  implicit def contextToSession(rc: RequestContext[_]) = rc.request.session

  def login: Action[AnyContent] = PublicAction { implicit rc =>
    Ok(html.login(loginForm))
  }
```

`RequestContext` is my own custom class wrapper of the Play2 `Request`.

My scala view starts with:

```
@(form: Form[(String,String,Boolean)])(implicit flash: Flash, session: Session,rc: utils.RequestContext[_])
```

But the compiler says:

> could not find implicit value for parameter flash: play.api.mvc.Flash

Can someone explain to me why it doesn't work? 
Perhaps we can't use implicit conversions for implicit parameters?

Then can someone explain to me why there is already a working implicit conversion from the Play2 request to Session/Flash and when I do it it doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you end up having multiple implicit parameters, some of which are members properties of the others, there is something wrong in your design.

```
class B
class C

class A {
  val b:B = _
  val c:C = _ 

}

def myMethod(someData:String)(implicit a:A, b:B, c:C) {

}
```

In fact, what you want to have inside your method are the B and the C members of that A. However, with such a signature one can provide a given A and a B and a C which have nothing to do with that A. The right signature would be the following

```
  def myMethod(someData:String)(implicit a:A) {
    // trick to import members variable
    import a._
    println(b)
    println(c)
  }
```

Comment: That's totally right, the 3 parameters are not required since my wrapper contains all the required data

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm it seems it works fine with:

```
implicit def contextToRequest(implicit rc: RequestContext[_]) = rc.request
```

And i don't need the 2 other methods since there would be an ambiguity because Play2 already provides implicit convertion of Request to Flash/Session